# Tensorflow's Multi_Gpu_Model crashes Ubuntu 18.04 OS when using all 4 GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

I am setting up Multi-GPU-model using Tensorflow on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop. I run the code on 4 NVIDIA RTX 2080 TI and compile the model using the CPU. The same code functions on Windows 10 OS, in case of the Ubuntu, it crashes and the system goes to reboot. Where do I check or change? is it is OS/code?

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = create_image_model()

# make the model parallel
model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=G)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)` to your session or estimator config. In the unlikely event this doesn't help, try switching IOMMU off in UEFI.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu